# Send an event from Listview (which is in a Fragment) to an existing activity via the Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `ListView` which is in a `Fragment`. Each row display a set of 4 `buttons`.
Each `button` has an `OnClickListener` defined in the `Adapter` Class. Everything is working well and i can diplay the `ID` of the clicked `button`.
My problem is how the send this `ID` to the activity (who hold the `Fragment` where the `ListView` is defined) via this `Fragment`. I'm stuck since 1 week till now !!!

Please remember that this activity is already existing and she is the one who already launched the fragment.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write one method in the Activity class,

```
public void setButtonClick(int buttonId){
// do your task
}
```

and from your adapter class

```
((YourActivity)fragment.getActivity()).setButtonClick(id);
```

But you need to pass fragment instance to the adapter using its constructor.

New Edits as per your code posted here,

```
class ArticleSetAdapter{

//  Variables

    private ArticleFragment context;

    // Constructor
    public ArticleSetAdapter(ArticleFragment context, ArrayList<ArrayList<Article>> articleSetArray) {
        super(context.getActivity(), 0, articleSetArray);
    this.context = context;
    }
```

and in your adapter onClick,

//  the OnClickListener handler method

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Integer artID = (Integer) ((Button) v).getTag();

        ((youractivity.class)context.getActivity())..setButtonClick(artID)

        makeText(getContext(), "CLICK: " + artID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
};
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: do you have list adapter class?

Comment: you have added source in answer, you need to add that by editing your question, I am gonna update my answer as per your code

Comment: Sorry Silvans, its my first time to pose a question. Hope that my code help you understanding my problem